# Change the pin location in Ti.Map

Tags: android, ios, annotations, maps, appcelerator

I'm developing an app and will work like an "**Uber App**": you have to select the location in the map and then send it to the server.
Now, to select the location, I put a pin with the `draggable` property set to `true`. This is a good way to select the location but my client want the same effect than the uber app. Moving the map instead of the pin, the pin stays in the center of the map.

How can I make that effect with titanium?

I am using:

> Appcelerator Studio, **build: 4.8.1.201612050850**
>
> SDK **6.0.2**
>
> Platform : **iOS/Android**

Comment: ok now what is the question or error??

Comment: Sorry... i already did the modifications.. thanks.

Comment: You should post a answer explaining how you solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Duncan, i mean the modifications to the original post, so my question can be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a view/imageview on top of the map that has the image in the center with `touchEnabled:false` so you still can access the map behind it.